# AutoMapper NU1001 fx/ dependency errors in a .NET Platform 5.4 Library

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, automapper

I am a new developer working with ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core). In VS2015 I created a new class library project targeting .NET Platform 5.4 (`dotnet5.4`), and added the `AutoMapper` NuGet package, version 4.2.0.

I am getting the following errors, basically for all the System packages:

> 3>C:\Users\Andrew\OneDrive\Development\Visual Studio\APT\src\Fideles.Service\project.json : .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency fx/Microsoft.CSharp  could not be resolved.
>   3>C:\Users\Andrew\OneDrive\Development\Visual Studio\APT\src\Fideles.Service\project.json : .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency fx/System.Collections  could not be resolved.
>   3>C:\Users\Andrew\OneDrive\Development\Visual Studio\APT\src\Fideles.Service\project.json : .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency fx/System.Collections.Concurrent  could not be resolved.

But I think according to the NuGet package description it should be supported:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/

As you can see from the screenshot these packages seem to be referenced twice; once correctly and once incorrectly with an `fx/` prefix:

[image]

This is my `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Fideles.Services Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Andrew" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-*",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-*",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-*",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-*",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-*"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.0",
    "Fideles.Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "Fideles.Data": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that dotnet5.4 [isn't supported](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1124) by AutoMapper 4.2.0. Depending on what you're targeting it may be possible to change dotnet5.4 to something else (dnxcore50 for example).

I have the same issue on a number of my own libraries and I'm waiting for netstandard to take care of all this.

Comment: Thank you @Damien I had assumed that dotnet5.1 support implied that dotnet5.4 would also be supported. I will wait for the netstandard changes then.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind interrupting your Visual Studio workflow you can get your application to build by doing the following.

1. Make sure you have the new dotnet CLI installed
   (https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/)
2. Run `dotnet restore` from the command line in your project folder

This sorted out the the build errors. I then  deleted my lock files and ran Clean and Rebuild on the solution for good measure.